# SQLite-Net Extensions: removing detail records in Master/Detail scenario

Tags: sqlite-net

What is the proper way to remove dentail records ?

I have Stock entity (master) in OneToMany relation with Valuation entity (detail).

I retrive one Stock entity with its related Valuations. Then I remove an entity from Valuations list and call UpdateWithChildrenAsync.

The result of this update is that in the removed valuation the foreign key is NULL instead I want this record to be physically removed.

```
namespace TestSQLitePCL
{
    public class Stock
    {
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int? Id { get; set; }
        public string Symbol { get; set; }

        [OneToMany(CascadeOperations = CascadeOperation.All)]
        public List<Valuation> Valuations { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace TestSQLitePCL
{
    public class Valuation
    {
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int? Id { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey(typeof(Stock))]
        public int StockId { get; set; }
        public DateTime Time { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
    }
}



...
stock.Valuations.RemoveAt(0);
...
await _connection.UpdateWithChildrenAsync(stock);
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing an element from a relationship is not supposed to delete that object from the database.

You can either delete them manually when removing them from the relationship (making sure nobody else is referencing that record):

```
// Remove valuation from stock list
stock.Valuations.Remove(valuation);
await valuation.DeleteAsync();
```

Or delete orphaned objects on a regular basis to keep the database clean.

```
// Delete orphaned valuations
conn.Execute("DELETE FROM Valuation WHERE stock_id = 0");
```